# How to achieve a spark effect like http://ellislab.com/codeigniter using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I want to recreate an effect like on http://ellislab.com/codeigniter where there are sparks flying in the background of their orange "hero" lead in.

I looked at the jQuery behind it and looks complex, are there any libraries out there or anything "template / tutorial" wise you could point in the direction of?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, the nice thing about JavaScript is that it's client side, so you can see *exactly* how they do it. It's a pretty simple bit of javascript, and they just use css to style the sparks. Here's the main bunch of code that runs the sparks:

```
// Let some sparks fly in a somewhat randomly timed fashion
          this.startSpark = function(){
            if (me.sparkInterval != null) return;
            me.sparkInterval = setInterval(function(){
              var opac = Math.max(.15, Math.random() - .4),
                  size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 120 + 30),
                  spark = $('<div/>').addClass('spark')
                    .css({
                      'width': size,
                      'height': size,
                      'opacity': opac, 
                      '-moz-opacity': opac
                    });

              $wrapper.append(
                spark
                .css(
                  {
                    "bottom": "-100px",
                    "left": (Math.random() * 100) + "%"
                  }
                )
                .animate(
                  {
                    "bottom": "800px",
                  },
                  Math.floor(Math.random()*3000+1000),
                  "linear",
                  function(){
                    $(this).remove(); // don't need the spark if we're in the dark
                  }
                )
              )
            }, 500)
          }
```

Basically, they create a 'spark' div, randomly set the opacity, width and height, and position, append it to the DOM, then randomly animate it, and when the animation is done, they remove it from the DOM. Here's the whole source file if you're not sure how to open inspect element or firebug: http://ellislab.com/asset/js/ci.js

I'm afraid I couldn't find any "animate random sparks" jQuery plugin for ya. Just count this as an adventure. Get in knee deep, learn some JavasScript, break stuff, and have fun! I'm sure with a little work and learning, you can get this working.

Comment: They use a file i have never heard of... http://ellislab.com/asset/css/img/products/ci-spark.svg what does this do?

Comment: SVG stands for "Scalable Vector Graphic." It's a type of vector graphic that is infinitely scalable. He uses that for the sparks. SVGs work the same way an Adobe Illustrator file works, but it's a non-proprietary format. Modern browsers can embed and use these files to create infinitely scalable graphics. Such is the case here.